# Compare two tables to find different values in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables like this :

table 1

```
|id| comments | class    |
|1 | bla bla  | positive |
|2 | bla bla  | negative |
```

table 2

```
|id| comments | class    |
|1 | bla bla  | positive |
|2 | bla bla  | positive |
```

I want to compare the `class` and store it to variable called `tp` if `class` in `table 1` and `table 2` are positive.

 If the `class` in `table 1` is negative and it is positive in `table 2` it will be stored in `fn`.

I've try but can't make it because I'm newbie. I hope someone can help me for this. Thank you.

After that I can use `tp` and `fn` in php to do some calculation.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Please show us desirable output from your sample tables

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, you should give sample output for both scenarios, as it is not clear which column you want to use in the variable. Use something like below.

This is assuming,

1. You want `id` in the variables,
2. You want to join based on `id` column.

Use the output of these queries -in the variables.

Note: I dont know PHP, but if query returns more than 1 row, then you might have to use an array or something to fetch each row separately in a loop.

```
select t1.id 
from table1 t1 
inner join table2 t2
on t1.id=t2.id
and t1.class='positive'
and t2.class='positive';

select t1.id 
from table1 t1 
inner join table2 t2
on t1.id=t2.id
and t1.class='negative'
and t2.class='positive';
```